# Linux processes without certain namespaces?

Tags: linux, namespace, network-namespaces

When chromium is running I see processes in `/proc/[PID]/` where some of the namespace links inside `/proc/[PID]/ns/`do link to *nothing*, that is, they cannot be `readlink`ed and return errors instead. Also an `ls -l` throws error for them. This applies only to some namespaces, such as the network namespace. This happens with superuser rights inside the root namespaces looking at `/proc/[PID]/ns/net` for some chromium-related processes.

The system is a recently updated Debian 9 Stretch.

Can someone please explain how it is possible that a process can be dejoined from certain namespaces completely? I've never seen anything being mentioned in the Linux namespace man pages, so how is this possible and what's the meaning?

Comment: I don't know, but it would be better to specify which error(s) you see.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this so far again, so it's really strange.